# Как добавить массив в Dictionary C#

Tags: c#

Есть Dictionary такого типа:

```
Dictionary<string, string> vocabulary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

В него необходимо добавить 2 заполненных массива типа string tx1 и tx2, пробовал добавить через цикл, не получается.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < tx1.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < tx2.Length; j++)
            {
                vocabulary.Add(tx1[i], tx2[j]);
            }
        }
```

Получаю исключение: "Элемент с тем же ключом уже был добавлен."
Как правильно заполнить? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: что значит `правильно заполнить`? Словарь - это сопоставление ключ-значение, где у вас ключ и где значение?

Comment: Подскажите, я правильно понял, что в одном массиве -- ключи, а во втором -- значения? Их длины равны?

Comment: Вот смотрите, Вы запускаете цикл внутри цикла, то есть для каждого значения из tx1 Вы пытаетесь добавить каждое значение из tx2. То есть пытаетесь tx2.Length раз добавить один и тот же ключ. На второй же итерации внутреннего цикла Вы, очевидно, получаете исключение.

Comment: tx1 ключ, tx2 значение, пример Home дом, если бы добавлял как vocabulary.Add("Home", "Дом");  Мне посоветовали использовать для связки слова и перевода Dictionary

Comment: Может вам нужно `Dictionary<string, string[]>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
       если массивы соответствуют ключу => значению

        for (int i = 0; i < tx1.Length; i++)

        {
            vocabulary.Add(tx1[i], tx2[i]);
        }
```

Comment: @Adyss вопрос в другом....для чего вам сначала заполнять массив, а потом словарь, если можно сразу же словарь.

Comment: Точно, помогло, спасибо большое) Просто изначально работал с 2 массивами.

Comment: @Adyss ксли помогло, не забудьте про галочку

Comment: Всегда напрягало вот это `i < tx1.Length`, я бы заменил на `i <Math.Min( tx1.Length, tx2.Length)` :)

Answer (score 5):

Даешь магию кортежей и LINQ - однострочник!

```
var keys = new[] {"one", "two", "three"};
var values = new[] {"oneV", "twoV", "threeV"};  
var dictionary = keys.Select((k, i)=>(k, i)).ToDictionary(x=>x.k, x=>values[x.i]);
```

Второй вариант, чуть более длинный

```
var dictionary = Enumerable.Range(0, Math.Min(keys.Length, values.Length))
                           .ToDictionary(i => keys[i], i=>values[i]).Dump();
```

Comment: мог использовать последовательное перечисление: `Enumerable.Range(1, count).ToDictionary(i=>keys[i], x=>values[i]);` Более короткий LINQ ... даешь!

Comment: @dgzargo ну для этого надо знать `count`, что уже вторая строка (или более длинная первая), но тоже годнота!

Comment: Мне кажется, что `.ToDictionary` это хорошо с точки зрения семантики, поэтому я бы предпочёл именно этот вариант, чем `for`.

Comment: спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Словарь содержит пары "ключ-значение". Если значение может быть не уникальным, т.е. повторяться, то ключ должен быть уникальным, т.к. доступ к значениям словаря производится по ключу. Перед добавлением пары "ключ-значение" в словарь, можно проверить наличие/отсутствие ключа и на основе результата определять дальнейшее поведение:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < tx1.Length; i++) {
    if(vocabulary.ContainsKey(tx1[i])) {
        Console.WriteLine($"key {tx1[i]} already exists");
        continue;
    }
    vocabulary.Add(tx1[i], tx2[i]);
}
```

#### Ссылки по теме

- [Dictionary.ContainsKey(TKey)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.containskey?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: воу воу, зачем 2 цикла то? К тому же это для всех ключей добавит одно и то же  значение

Comment: @tym32167 я сам сперва не заметил фигню 2х циклов )

Comment: @tym32167 сорян

Comment: Есть вариант ещё короче :) `vocabulary[tx1[i]]=tx2[i];` и не надо ключ проверять )

Comment: @tym32167 согласен с тем, что он короче :) Но при таком подходе значения будут перетираться. Я просто хотел показать, что значение ключа можно проверять перед добавлением пары и на основе его наличия или отсутствия решать далее, что нужно делать.

Comment: ok ok, тогда ладно :)

Comment: @XelaNimed если у автора для английского слова есть несколько переводов, то тогда можно сделать `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` - проблем с перетиранием уже не будет :)